# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase-push-notifications'. > Configuration with name 'compile' not found

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Here's version of the packages

```
"react": "18.0.0", "react-native": "0.69.0", "react-native-firebase-push-notifications": "^2.0.2"
```

I installed react-native-firebase-push-notifications and after that I ran npx react-native run-android but, I am getting this error.

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development 
environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
 Build file '/Users/hafizsameed/Documents/right-hand/rn-0.69.0- 
 project/app/node_modules/react-native-firebase-push- 
 notifications/android/build.gradle' 
 line: 179

 What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase-push-notifications'.

  Configuration with name 'compile' not found.
```

my android/build.gradle

```
repositories {
 google()
 mavenCentral()
  }
dependencies {
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1") 
  classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
  classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
  // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
  // in the individual module build.gradle files
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
   }
 }

allprojects {
 repositories {
  maven {
   // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm 
   url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
   } 
 maven {
  // Android JSC is installed from npm
  url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
  } 
 mavenCentral {
 // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
  // older versions over there.
 content {
   excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
 }
  }
 google()
  maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
 }
```

my app/build.gradle (added code)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens as `compile` is not available anymore.

There are 2 workarounds to fix this.

**Workaround 1**

Go to the file

```
node_modules/react-native-firebase-push-notifications/android/build.gradle`
```

a) Add

`configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)` before `afterEvaluate` configuration

b) and change

```
classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList())
```

to

```
classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('implementation').asList())
```

But this is not really a good solution, as when you install the dependencies again, you'll have to redo this again.

So either you can create a post script for the same or go for the following solution,

**Workaround 2**

Go to `<your-project>/android/build.gradle` file and add the following

```
subprojects { subproject ->
        if(project['name'] == 'react-native-firebase-push-notifications'){
            project.configurations { compile { } }
        }
}
```

That's it.

I would say workaround 2 is a better option as we don't need to do anything on installing the dependencies again.

I hope this helps!